# Creating a banner for 10th birthday celebrations

Tags: discussion, community, 10th-anniversary

This follows up on [How should we celebrate 10 years of Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19187/how-should-we-celebrate-10-years-of-ask-ubuntu). [The proposal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19189/527764) to create a banner was well-received and it [was suggested](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19187/how-should-we-celebrate-10-years-of-ask-ubuntu#comment41337_19189) that this would be a good way to link to celebration events.

---

The idea is to display some kind of banner on the site around Ask Ubuntu's 10th anniversary in October.

Please post your ideas, designs and other thoughts relating to creating such a banner or banner-like thing here!

---

**Note**: Other ideas may also be taken forward. Everyone is hereby encouraged to post on meta or [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) (feel free to ping me) about implementing any other celebration ideas.

Comment: How much control do you have over the banner? Just the text or can you change colours, add a background etc?

Comment: @MarkKirby We haven't got a banner button as such - sorry I should have made that clear - we can only put a notice in the sidebar. Will have to ask employees to implement.

Comment: Good question by @MarkKirby what are the allowed banners in terms of size, format, etc. Or is this similar to the sidebar adverts - [Community Promotion Ads — 2019](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18388/community-promotion-ads-2019)

Comment: @Parto sorry I actually don't know. It sounds like if we tell them what we want, they can do it (Catija said "probably"). If you are interested, maybe it would be easier to put you in touch with the folks who would be able to put it up?

Comment: Hi @Zanna No problem. Kindly refer to me someone I can talk to about this.

Comment: @Parto so sorry I was not able to get any information for you, but amazingly Catija did get a banner done for us at the last minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catija sorted a nice banner for us linking to the [events post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19334/happy-10th-anniversary-to-ask-ubuntu)

[image: screenshot of askubuntu.com front page with banner at top of right sidebar]